# AEM 6.3 create page with fileupload within cq dialog

Tags: xml, file-upload, aem, dam

I'm new to AEM and I want to create a page template with fileupload (pdf, jpeg) within the cq dialog.
I only found a way with thumbnail, but I can't find a way to upload correctly.

The thumbnail idea/ structure is commint from 'create collection'.

My xml structure:

```
<form
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form"
    class="foundation-form content-container"
    foundationForm="{Boolean}true"
    maximized="{Boolean}true"
    method="post"
    style="vertical">
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <thumbnail
            granite:class="share-resource-image grid"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="dam/gui/coral/components/commons/thumbnail"
            asset="${empty param.item ? requestPathInfo.suffix : param.item}"
            defaultPreview="{Boolean}true">
            <actions jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <upload
                granite:id="thumbnail-upload-button"
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/fileupload"
                autoStart="{Boolean}false"
                mimeTypes="[image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf]"
                multiple="{Boolean}false"
                name="coverImage"
                renderReadOnly="{Boolean}true"
                sizeLimit="100000000"
                text="Dokument hochladen"
                uploadUrl="will_be_replaced"
                useHTML5="{Boolean}false"/>
            </actions>
        </thumbnail>
        <removemanualthumbnail
            granite:id="removemanualthumbnail"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/hidden"
            name="removemanualthumbnail"
            value="false"/>
    </items>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<fileupload
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="files"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <file
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/fileupload"
        autoStart="{Boolean}true"
        cq-msm-lockable="/file"
        fieldLabel="the label for the field"
        mimeTypes="[image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf]"
        multiple="{Boolean}false"
        name="./file"
        sizeLimit="100000000"
        text="Dokument hochladen"
        uploadUrl="/content/dam/someurl"
        uploadUrlBuilder=""/>
    </items>
</fileupload>
```

Comment: I just tried the solution, but the fieldset and the fileupload is not showing in the dialog. I think it's not possible 'for me' to create a fileupload within the page creation process.Maybe there will be an update for AEM 6.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this as well. Two things helped me:

Referencing the core components http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/apps/core/wcm/components/page/v1/page/cq%3Adialog/content/items/tabs/items/thumbnail/items/column/items/thumbnail/upload to make the following dialog...

```
<upload jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/fileupload" 
    text="Upload Image" name="./image/file.sftmp" 
    sizeLimit="1000000"
    multiple="{Boolean}false"
    async="{Boolean}true"  
    autostart="{Boolean}false"  
    granite:class="cq-wcm-fileupload" 
    uploadUrl="will_be_replaced">
      <granite:data jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" cq-msm-lockable="./image" />
</upload>
```

However the above will not work without the extra clientlibs on the cq:dialog node http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#/apps/core/wcm/components/page/v1/page/cq%3Adialog

```
<jcr:root jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
  sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
  extraClientlibs="[cq.common.wcm,core.wcm.page.properties,cq.wcm.msm.properties]" 
 ...
```